Find local MAX values in a column
I need the highest value of each 22 rows, but the 18 rows after the scanned rows are consistently not relevant, I need to leave these out. So for example: '=MAX(B40:B68)' & then I need to leave the next 18 (B69:B87) out, then, I need highest value of (B88:B116) etc.
I tried filtering based on time, but that is about the same effort I realized quickly.. I really would not know what else to try, but there sure as heck should be a way right?

Excel and Google Sheets are two separate and distinct products, with a lot of differences in syntax and functionality. If your question is about Excel, then the Google Sheets tag does not apply. Tags have relevance and meaning here - please do not spam them by using them inappropriately.

B40:B68 has 29, B69:B87 has 19, and B88:B116 has 29 rows. Please edit your question and correct the mistakes.

Max of X Rows Skipping Y Rows
=LET(data,A2:A15,max_rows,3,skip_rows,2,
    d,WRAPROWS(data,max_rows+skip_rows,""),
    BYROW(d,LAMBDA(r,MAX(TAKE(r,max_rows)))))


Edit

The previous can be simplified with...

=LET(data,A2:A15,max_rows,3,skip_rows,2,
    d,TAKE(WRAPROWS(data,max_rows+skip_rows,""),,max_rows),
    BYROW(d,LAMBDA(r,MAX(r))))

... or, if ETA lambdas are available, with even...
=LET(data,A2:A15,max_rows,3,skip_rows,2,
    BYROW(TAKE(WRAPROWS(data,max_rows+skip_rows,""),,max_rows),MAX))

... or hardcoded with...
=BYROW(TAKE(WRAPROWS(A2:A15,5,""),,3),MAX)


Assuming you have Excel 365: rowsCount specifies how many rows are used to calculate the local maximum and rowsSkip skips the specified number of rows:
=LET(
    range,B:B,
    rowsCount, 4,
    rowsSkip, 3,
    rowsTotal, COUNT(range),
    rowsStart, SEQUENCE((rowsTotal/rowsCount)-1,1,1,rowsCount+rowsSkip),
    localMax, MAP(rowsStart, LAMBDA(i, MAX(INDEX(range, SEQUENCE(rowsCount, 1, i, 1), SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(range),1,rowsSkip+1))))),
    localMax)


Based on timestamp column:
=LET(
    col_b_high, B2:B24,
    col_c_low, C2:C24,
    time_stamp, E2:E24,
    date_, TEXTBEFORE(time_stamp, " "),
    time_, TEXTAFTER(time_stamp, " "),
    u_date, SORT(UNIQUE(date_)),
    within_eth, TIMEVALUE(time_) < TIME(15, 30, 0),
    highs_and_lows, REDUCE(
        {"Date", "High", "Low"},
        u_date,
        LAMBDA(acc, cur,
            VSTACK(
                acc,
                HSTACK(
                    cur,
                    MAX(FILTER(col_b_high, (date_ = u_date) * within_eth)),
                    MIN(FILTER(col_c_low, (date_ = u_date) * within_eth))
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    highs_and_lows
)


